# How to add 'required' validation to aui:input dynamically from js

Tags: javascript, liferay, liferay-aui

here is aui:input

```
<aui:input name="price" id="price" showRequiredLabel="false" value="">
  <aui:validator>
    // I have some custom validator for price format
  </aui:validator>
</aui:input>
```

I have a radio button group. on click of one of those radio buttons, I want to apply required aui validator dynamically. I tried adding `required=true` from js, that works but as a 'HTML5 required' validation. I want to achieve this through AUI validation.

Answer (score 3):

You can fetch the formValidator using Liferay JS Utils:

```
var liferayForm = Liferay.Form.get('YOUR-FORM-ID');
liferayForm.formValidator.get('rules')['ID-OF-YOUR-INPUT-FIELD']={required: true};
```

Now you input field will be required (client side validation).

Answer (score 0):

JSP evaluation works server side, generating different markup (and potentially scripting) on the DOM. Thus it won't be a simple attribute that you'd have to change, but more complex.

In order to validate if you'd really want to go that way, I'd go the following way:

- Generate the page once without the validator, capture the resulting HTML
- Then redeploy the portlet, now with the validator, capture the page source again
- diff both results to see what's generated.

Once you've identified if it's worth adding the required validator at runtime or not - decide what you want to do.

Note that you'd also have the opposite way, if adding a validator is too complex: Consider to hard code the validator and deactivate it at runtime - this might be easier.

Edit after @Klimiuk's comment: You might be happier [with aui-form-validator](https://alloyui.com/tutorials/form-validator) rather than hunting down the JSP output, because tags, due to their server-side processing, easily get messy.

Comment: I think he is trying to add javascript validator, when he is clicking the radio button and he doesn't know how to use AUI aui-form-validator module

Comment: I just want to apply required validator dynamically